# Read indexes currently used by DataGridView with enabled RowFilter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataTable as source. In DataGridView I want to add item in context menu something like "Select Filtered". When I click it, it should set all rows in column 0 (which is bool type) to true. Rows in data table that are not currently displayed in DataGridView (because of RowFilter) should not be affected. How to do this?:)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Rows.Count works with RowFilter and indexing works too.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    dataGrid[selectionColumnIndex, i].Value = true;
}
```